# Porque quando uso AJAX a função não funciona?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        LoadMods();

        $(".mod").click(function(){
            var id = $(this).data("id");

            alert("Entrou");

            $.ajax({
                url: '../crud/load_mods_info.php?id='+id,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){

                }        
            }); 
        });
    });

function LoadMods(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '../crud/load_mods.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var html = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                html += "<li><a href='#' class='mod' data-id='"+data[i].id+"'>"+data[i].nome+"</a></li>";
            }

            $('#myUL').html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="myUL" class="mt-3"></ul>
<a href="#" class="mod" data-id="10">Teste</a>
```

O que está acontecendo é:
Quando a função LoadMods cria a tag li dentro do ul e eu clico no link, não executa o jquery $(".mod").click()...

Porém, se eu clico em Teste, que eu criei, funciona normalmente, ou seja, da o alert("Entrou"). Sendo que o código é o mesmo: `<a href="#" class="mod" data-id="10">Teste</a>`

Não sei se fui muito claro, espero que sim!

Comment: É melhor revisar seu código, pois tentei reproduzir aqui e sem alterar nada ele funciona, veja: http://jsfiddle.net/kx5yectL/

Comment: Obrigado Sam! Resolveu a minha dúvida.

Comment: Show de bola!...